# The use of euler function to calculate the order of an element

Tags: group-theory

Just trying to check if I understand the material right. I would like to calculate $o(5)$ for $U_6$ (or $\mathbb{Z}_6^\times$). On one hand I think that we need to use the euler function to do so. But on the other hand we have the following theorem:
$$o(a)=min\{n\in\mathbb{N}|a^n=e\}$$
So as I understand, I need to find all the minimal $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $5^n=1$ (although I'm not sure that $e=1$). From my previous thread I learned that $5^n=5+...+5\,(mod\,6)$. But there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $5^n=1$.

Also what will happen with bigger numbers? For example how to calculate $o(5)$ for $U_{27}$?

Answer (score 1):

$5^n$ means repeating the group operation on $5$ $n$ times. Since we're dealing with the multiplicative group here, the group operation is multiplication, not addition.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay. Although there is still no solution for $5^n=1$ right?

Comment: @vesii There is. $5^2=25=1$ mod6

Comment: oh right! and how the euler equation comes in handy? can we calculate all of the numbers?